# Visualisation of sorting algorithms

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, d3.js, visualize

I'm trying to visualise sorting algorithms using d3.js but i'm kinda stuck. When i try to re draw the graphs by including it the sorting loop. the graph only shows the final value. Same thing happened after using the **setInterval** function. I have included the script without all **timer functions** below (didn't include the settime function)

```js
var arr = new Array(10, 34, 66, 3, 56, 45, 67, 43, 45, 7);
var wi = 500;
var he = 500;
var temp = 0;

//Scaling
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", wi)
  .attr("height", he);

for (l = 9; l > 0; l--) {

    for( p=0;p<l; p++){
                      if(arr[p]>arr[p+1]){
                          swap(p,arr);
                       
                                 
                         }
                      
                  }
  updatevisualization(arr);
}

function swap(n, arr) {
  temp = arr[n];
  arr[n] = arr[n + 1];
  arr[n + 1] = temp;
}

//visualizaiton
function updatevisualization(xx) {
  var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(xx)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return (5 * d);
    })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return i * 20;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is synchronous and browser GUI updates only take place when the JavaScript code is done. You won't see anything happening until you return from your function. Use `setTimeout` (like you wrote you tried).

Comment: @Amit I tried. no luck still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = new Array(10, 34, 66, 3, 56, 45, 67, 43, 45, 7);
var wi = 500;
var he = 500;
var temp = 0;

//Scaling
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", wi)
  .attr("height", he);
updatevisualization(arr);

setTimeout(function(){
  var nAr = arr.sort(function(a,b){return a>b;});//Sorting numbers in ascending order
  canvas.html('');//removing old bars('rect's)
  update(nAr);//Creating bar('rect')s with new sorted array.
}, 1000);


/*
for (l = 9; l > 0; l--) {

      var myVar = setTimeout(function(){  for( p=0;p<l; p++){
                      if(arr[p]>arr[p+1]){
                          swap(p,arr);
                       
                                 
                         }
                      
                  }}, 1000);
  updatevisualization(arr);
}
*/


function swap(n, arr) {
  temp = arr[n];
  arr[n] = arr[n + 1];
  arr[n + 1] = temp;
}

//visualizaiton
function updatevisualization(xx) {
  var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(xx)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return (5 * d);
    })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return i * 20;
    });
}

function update(numbers) {
canvas.selectAll('bar').data(arr).exit().remove();
  var selection = canvas
    .selectAll("bar").data(numbers);

  selection.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return (5 * d);
    })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return i * 20;
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I've just added little code to sort array and creating elements again.
Try to observe the code.

Comment: Thank You!!!!. I solved the problem finally by using your update function. Inside the for loop i called  canvas.html(''); update(are); per single turn and i got what i needed :)

Comment: Ooh...Good
Finally You got what you looking for.
:D

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are running setTimeout function and updateVisualization routine multiple times in one pass, which is perceived as an instant operation as it basically runs in a subsecond time, actually under a millisecond.

When all the execution scope of the sorting algorithm exits, and JS starts next cycles of the event loop. Basically it's now just sleeping and waiting for external events and timer events.

Eventually, around after 1000 ms JS starts to schedule all the sorting algorithm steps as you requested with setTimeout function. The screen never gets updated, because all the screen updating code is already finished in the first event cycle along with the sorting algorithm.

To get updates scheduled on time, you could split the loop in chunks of job, scheduled separately:

Here is what a chunk of job should do:
 Update screen;
 If next step is needed, do the step and schedule the next chunk;

The fist chunk is started manually, it's not scheduled by a previous chunk.

```
var startChunk = function(l) {
  updatevisualization(arr);
  if (l == 0) return;
  for (p = 0; p < l; p++) {
    if (arr[p] > arr[p + 1]) {
      swap(p, arr);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    startChunk(l - 1);
  }, 1000);
};

// Schedule the first chunk
startChunk(9);
```

As as side note, you should use something like `console.log("What's on at " + new Date());` to debug asynchronous code and know what's happening and when.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is i was looking for. From the Aswers above i was able to get the things together ;) :D

```html
<!Doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>

  <title>Visualizer App Beta!!</title>
</head>


<body>

  <script>
    var arr = new Array(10, 34, 66, 3, 56, 45, 67, 43, 45, 7);
    var wi = 500;
    var he = 500;
    var temp = 0;
     // var pos=0;
     // draww(arr);
     //    var x= d3.scale.linear().domain([3-67]).range([3-he]);
    var canvas = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", wi)
      .attr("height", he);


    var l = 9; //Scaling


    var startChunk = function(l) {
      //updatevisualization(arr);
      canvas.html('');
      update(arr);
      if (l == 0) return;
      for (p = 0; p < l; p++) {
        if (arr[p] > arr[p + 1]) {
          swap(p, arr);
        }
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        startChunk(l - 1);
      }, 1000);
    };

     // Schedule the first chunk
    startChunk(9);





    function swap(n, arr) {

      temp = arr[n];
      arr[n] = arr[n + 1];
      arr[n + 1] = temp;


    }


   
     //visualizaiton

    function update(numbers) {
      canvas.selectAll('bar').data(arr).exit().remove();
      var selection = canvas
        .selectAll("bar").data(numbers);

      selection.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return (5 * d);
        })
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return i * 20;
        });
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Nice to hear you have a solution now, however you should not post a rework of another answer, just accept a quality answer if you think it's best for your solution.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy  oh Sorry for that. I'm kinda new here. For my last post i got -7.